# UITableView crash if I delete rows too fast

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have an app with a UITableView which can delete cells using a row action. However, if I do two in quick succession, the app crashes with a BAD_EXEC.

The problem is clearly timing related. I'm asking the table to do something else before it's quite finished with the old. It could be the animations or it could be the removal of cells.

Either way, calling reloadData on the tableview before I start seems to fix it. There are two problems with this solution.

Firstly, reloadData interferes with some of the niceness of the usual row removal animations. It's no biggie but I'd prefer it with all animations intact.

Secondly, I still don't fully understand what's happening.

Can any one help me understand and/or suggest a better solution?

Here's the code...

```
-(void) rowActionPressedInIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath timing:(Timing) doTaskWhen
{
    [self.tableView reloadData]; // This is my current solution

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    ToDoTask *toDo = [self removeTaskFromTableViewAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    toDo.timing = doTaskWhen;  // Just some data model updating. Has no effect on anything else here.

    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

removeTaskFromTableView is mostly code to work out if I need to delete an entire section or a row. I've confirmed the app makes the right choice and the bug works either way so the only relevant line from the method is...

```
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
```

**Edit:** I have noticed that the standard delete row action provided by the system does not allow me to move that fast. There is an in-built delay which (presumably) prevents this exact problem.

Comment: You need to update Array as well. Add/remove object at respective index.

Comment: what about your data source does get updated also ?

Comment: The table only displays items with a certain timing so the line where I change the timing of the toDo object is the update. Anyway, it only happens if I go fast whereas if I didn't update the model, all sorts of problems would happen every time I did anything.

Comment: What happens, if you dispatch the delete row message each via the run loop?

Comment: No luck. I delayed for a set time as well and found it had to be 0.6 seconds to make it work safely. I'm coming to the conclusion that the problem is the row action animation - which I have no access to at all as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) rowActionPressedInIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath timing:(Timing) doTaskWhen
{
   // [self.tableView reloadData]; // This is my current solution

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    ToDoTask *toDo = [self removeTaskFromTableViewAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    toDo.timing = doTaskWhen;  // Just some data model updating. Has no effect on anything else here.

    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Or try to reload table view in main thread.